# Optimizing Insertions into an SQLite Database with JDBC

Tags: java, sqlite, optimization, jdbc

I'm writing the backend for a java http server for a class project and I have to insert a few records into a database using jdbc. The maximum number of insertions I have at one time is currently 122, which takes a whopping 18.7s to execute, about 6.5 insertions per second. This is outrageously slow, since the server needs to be able to respond to the request that inserts the records in less than 5s, and a real server would be expected to be many times faster. I'm pretty sure that this has something to do with the code or my declaration of the table schema, but I can't seem to find the bottleneck anywhere. The table schema looks like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Events (
    ID varchar(38) primary key,
    ownerName varchar(32) not null,
    personID varchar(38) not null,
    latitude float not null,
    longitude float not null,
    country varchar(64) not null,
    city varchar(128) not null,
    eventType varchar(8) not null,
    year int not null,
    foreign key (ownerName)
        references Users (userName)
            on delete cascade
            on update cascade,
    foreign key (ID)
        references People (ID)
            on delete cascade
            on update cascade
);
```

and the code to perform the insertions is the following function

```java
public class EventAccessor {
    private Connection handle;
    ...

    public void insert(Event event) throws DataInsertException {
        String query = "insert into Events(ID,ownerName,personID,latitude,longitude,country,"
                 + "city,eventType,year)\nvalues(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        try (PreparedStatement stmt = handle.prepareStatement(query)) {
            stmt.setString(1, event.getID());
            stmt.setString(2, event.getUsername());
            stmt.setString(3, event.getPersonID());
            stmt.setDouble(4, event.getLatitude());
            stmt.setDouble(5, event.getLongitude());
            stmt.setString(6, event.getCountry());
            stmt.setString(7, event.getCity());
            stmt.setString(8, event.getType());
            stmt.setInt(9, event.getYear());

            stmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new DataInsertException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Where `Event` is a class that holds an entry for the schema and `DataInsertionException` is a simple exception defined elsewhere in the API. I was instructed to use `PreparedStatement` because it's apparently "more safe" that using a `Statement`, but I have the choice to switch, so if it's faster I'll gladly change the code. The function that I use to insert the 122 entries is actually a wrapper for an array of `Event` objects that looks like this

```java
void insertEvents(Event[] events) throws DataInsertException {
    for (Event e : events) {
        insert(e);
    }
}
```

I'm willing to try anything to improve performance at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I disabled auto commits on the JDBC connection with `connection.setAutoCommit(false)` and performance increased by over 1000x. New benchmarks show that inserting 122 records was complete in a mere in 0.008265739s, a speed of about 14,000 insertions per second, which is closer to what I was expecting.